# How to check is IP/website is online using WebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

I wanna make a tool that checks a IP range for example, I just input: 12.34.56.* and the tool should go from 12.23.56.0 to 12.23.56.255. I made this part, and I tried using ping, but it's not working for what I need. I have some IPs that are working, and the pinger tells me that they are not working.

I read a lot of questions here about webrequest, and I think (from what I read) the best method is to download the website head, and check if it's null or not. I tried lot of answers posted in similar questions, but not working.

PS: I also wanna set a timeout of 3000 milliseconds or so.

Comment: so show your code and ask a specific code-related question.

Comment: -1 no sample/no code question. Also obviously you need more stuff to implement port scanner. Not every site will respond meaningfully on root even if one is present...

Comment: And not everyone will respond to a ping :). Did you try to "ping" the IPs using CMD? What are the results there?

Comment: Many web servers don't respond to a ping (e.g. cnn.com  microsoft.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - based on `StatusCode`

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("...."); //Adjust your adress
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
  System.Console.Write("is KO");
}
else
...
```